# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an hermitian matrix, Projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My quantum mech teacher told me to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of some matrices without resorting to boring computations when possible. I was trying to find them for the following matrix:
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$
Thanks to what I learned in the previous course I followed, I immediately noticed that this matrix is just a projector multiplied by a scalar, namely: I can rewrite it as:
$$M = k \cdot P_{\mathbf{\hat{u}_1}}$$
where $\mathbf{\hat{u}}$ is the unit vector on which I'm projecting, in our case it's easy to see that:
$$k = 3$$
$$ P_\mathbf{\hat{u}_1} = \mathbf{\hat{u}_1}\mathbf{\hat{u}^\ast_1}, \mathbf{\hat{u}_1} = \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right]^T$$
Now, noticing that our original matrix is hermitian (symmetric with only real coefficients, and it is also associated with a self-adjoint operator), I can write the spectral representation of $M$ as follows:
$$ M = \sum_{k=1}^{3} \lambda_k P_k \Rightarrow \{\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2  = \lambda_3 = 0 \}$$
Furthermore, I already know that the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is exactly $\mathbf{u}_1$.

This method turned out to be alright, except for one big flaw: I can't derive the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_{2,3}$. Is there a way to reconstruct them from all the pieces of information I gathered? If this weren't the case, then I'd have to discard my approach. In the latter scenario, is there a quick way or some sort of clever trick to notice for computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix I was given: what I know is that if a matrix is hermitian, then it only admits real-valued eigenvectors. This doesn't seem to be of much help though.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspace associated with the zero eigenvalues consists of the kernel of the projection $P_{\bf \hat u_1}$, which is just all the vectors perpendicular to $\bf \hat u_1$, or the vectors $[x,y,z]^T$ with $x+y+z=0$.  Since this eigenspace has dimension 2, you have a choice of what basis you use to span it.  One choice would be to pick any two vectors out of the set $\{[2/\sqrt{6}, -1/\sqrt{6}, -1/\sqrt{6}]^T$, $[-1/\sqrt{6}, 2/\sqrt{6}, -1/\sqrt{6}]^T$, $[-1/\sqrt{6}, -1/\sqrt{6}, 2/\sqrt{6}]^T$}, although this is not an orthogonal basis; an example of an orthogonal (and orthonormal) basis is $\{[2/\sqrt{6}, -1/\sqrt{6}, -1/\sqrt{6}]^T, [0, 1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2}]^T\}$.

Comment: It's worth noting that the orthogonality of the eigenspaces is not unique to projection matrices, but will occur for any normal matrix, i.e. a matrix that commutes with its own adjoint. This includes any Hermitian matrices, orthogonal matrices, and many others.